# UI and Responsive Issues

Tags: html, sass

I am facing some alignment issues in one of my websites. Basically it's a responsive issue

I have created a Pure Css Vertical Timeline and beside that timeline there are multiple paragraphs describing what the timeline is about. Now the issue I am facing is that aligning all the paragraphs vertically as same height as the timeline.

Here are codes

SCSS

```css
.col-md-4 {
  @media #{$mq9b} {
    display: none;
  }
  @media #{$mq7b} {
    display: none;
  }
  .timeline {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    @media #{$mq7b} {
      padding-left: 60px;
      position: relative;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -86px;
    }
    &:before {
      content: ' ';
      background: $timeline_color;
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 29px;
      width: 3px;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 400;
      @media #{$mq7b} {
        position: absolute;
        left: 48px;
      }
    }
    li {
      margin: 90px 0;
      padding-left: 20px;
      position: relative;
      @media #{$tablet} {
        line-height: 34px;
      }
      &:before {
        content: ' ';
        background: $timeline_color;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 50%;
        left: -36px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        z-index: 400;
      }
      a {
        margin-left: 20px;
        color: $black;
        font: 20px $lato;
        position: relative;
        top: 8px;
      }
      i {
        position: absolute;
        top: 12px;
        left: -22px;
        z-index: 1000;
        color: $black;
        font-size: 24px;
      }
    }
  }
}

.col-md-8 {
  .paragraph_wrapper {
    .timeline_paragraphs {
      list-style-type: none;
      .only_mobile_disp {
        display: none;
        h6 {
          display: none;
          @media #{$mq9b} {
            display: block;
            font-size: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
            padding-bottom: 10px
          }
          @media #{$mq7b} {
            display: block;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
            padding-bottom: 10px
          }
          .disp_mobile {
            opacity: 0;
            @media #{$mq9b} {
              opacity: 1;
              padding-right: 20px;
              position: relative;
              font-size: 16px;
              padding-top: 10px;
            }
            @media #{$mq7b} {
              // opacity: 1;
              padding-right: 20px;
              position: relative;
              font-size: 16px;
              padding-top: 10px;
            }
            &:before {
              position: relative;
              z-index: 1;
            }
            &:after {
              position: absolute;
              top: 4px;
              left: 50%;
              width: 30px;
              height: 30px;
              background-color: $timeline_color;
              content: "";
              margin-left: -25px;
              @include border-radius(50%);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      li {
        margin: 90px 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
  <ul class="timeline">
    <li> <a href="#" class="float-right">2019</a> <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="float-right">2018</a> <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="float-right">2016</a> <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="float-right">2014</a> <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="float-right">2012</a> <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="float-right">2010</a> <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="float-right">2002</a> <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="float-right">1992</a> <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="float-right">1973</a> <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
  <div class="paragraph_wrapper">
    <ul class="timeline_paragraphs">
      <li class="only_mobile_disp">
        <h6><i class="fa fa-calendar disp_mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>2019</h6>
      </li>
      <li>
        Handed Over BANERGATTA CENTRAL, A Part of PRIMCO SPECTRUM.
      </li>
      <li class="only_mobile_disp">
        <h6><i class="fa fa-calendar disp_mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>2018</h6>
      </li>
      <li>
        The Pavilion Residential Project Handed Over, Union City a mixed Development project launched.
      </li>
      <li class="only_mobile_disp">
        <h6><i class="fa fa-calendar disp_mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>2016</h6>
      </li>
      <li>
        1.3 million sft of Workspace, Retail AND Hospitality ongoing and projected to complete Q1 2017. Handover of ‘FIESTA HOMES’ and 5 Ongoing Projects.
      </li>
      <li class="only_mobile_disp">
        <h6><i class="fa fa-calendar disp_mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>2014</h6>
      </li>
      <li>
        2 million stf of new commercial &amp; retail projects completed.Handover of &#39; watermark &#39; &amp; &#39; crystal cove &#39; commenced.
      </li>
      <li class="only_mobile_disp">
        <h6><i class="fa fa-calendar disp_mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>2012</h6>
      </li>
      <li>
        3 commercial projects completed. 5 residential projects launched.
      </li>
      <li class="only_mobile_disp">
        <h6><i class="fa fa-calendar disp_mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>2010</h6>
      </li>
      <li>
        SJR Primecorp is incorporated.
      </li>
      <li class="only_mobile_disp">
        <h6><i class="fa fa-calendar disp_mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>2002</h6>
      </li>
      <li>
        Commercial, Residential development begins under the new SJR identity.
      </li>
      <li class="only_mobile_disp">
        <h6><i class="fa fa-calendar disp_mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>1992</h6>
      </li>
      <li>
        First Commercial Project. SJR Towers for Infosys.
      </li>
      <li class="only_mobile_disp">
        <h6><i class="fa fa-calendar disp_mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>1973</h6>
      </li>
      <li>
        Founded by S Jayarama reddy. Begins with Infrastructure &dash; Airport Tarmacs, Flyover, Higways and Factories.
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `SCSS`  or `SASS` ?

Comment: @mplungjan it's SCSS

Comment: @mplungjan can you kindly come up with a solution it would have been helpful for me.